# Limit superior and limit inferior of sets

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I have searched for the answer in wikipedia and math stackexchange. However, I do not have any background in real analysis and all the answers seem very complicated to me to understand. I am wondering if anyone can provide an intuitive answer or a graphical answer to visualize the concept easily.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See [these questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limsup-and-liminf+elementary-set-theory). One characterization for a sequence $A_1,$ $A_2,$ $A_3,\;\ldots\;A_n,\;\ldots$ of sets: $\limsup A_n$ is the set consisting of all elements that belong to **infinitely many** of the sets in this sequence and $\liminf A_n$ is the set consisting of all elements that belong to at most **finitely many** of the sets in this sequence. FYI, some or all of the sets in such a sequence may be the same, and "infinitely many" and "finitely many" refer to the subscripts $1,\,2,\,3,\,\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

If $(\mathcal P,\leq)$ is a lattice (i.e. a poset s.t. all pair of element $(a,b)$ has an infimum and a supremum), then for a sequence $(a_n)\in \mathcal P^{\mathbb N}$, $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }a_n:=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\sup_{k\geq n}a_ n\quad \text{and}\quad  \liminf_{n\to \infty }a_n:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\inf_{k\geq n}a_k.$$

Now, consider $(\mathcal P(\mathbb R),\subset )$ is a lattice and $$\inf(A,B):=A\cap B\quad \text{and}\quad \sup(A,B):=A\cup B,$$
for all $A,B\in \mathcal P(\mathbb R)$.

So, for a sequence $(A_n)\in \mathcal P(\mathbb R)^{\mathbb N}$, $$\inf_{k\geq n}A_k=\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k,$$
and thus $$\liminf_{n\to \infty }A_n:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\inf_{k\geq n}A_k=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k.$$
And similarly, $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }A_n=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_k.$$

Comment: Given the OP's assertion "*I do not have any background in real analysis and all the answers seem very complicated to me to understand*", my guess is that your answer should include (probably at the beginning) a less symbolic description. For example, the OP probably doesn't know what $\mathcal P^{\mathbb N}$ means.